# jquery selector - selecting the 2nd span child inside each table row

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following mark-up:

```
<table>
<thead>
...
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>
      <span class='select_me' id='42'></span>
    </td>
     <td>
      <span class='select_me' id='43'></span>
     </td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>
      <span class='select_me' id='50'></span>
    </td>
     <td>
      <span class='select_me' id='54'></span>
     </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How would I go about selecting the 2nd or 1st span 'select_me' in each row?
I figure it's something like this - I want to get the id

```
$("td").each(function(){
v = $(this).children(".select_me:first").attr("id");
});
```

but it outputs 'undefined', any help would be appreciated

Comment: why (".big") ? you don't have any element with class "big"!

Comment: my bad... on my project, they're both big, but here, I switched only one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the [:eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/) selector:

```
$("tr").each(function() {
    var firstId = $("span.select_me:eq(0)", this).attr("id");
    var secondId = $("span.select_me:eq(1)", this).attr("id");
});
```

Since you only have two `<span>` elements per row, you can also use the [:first](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) and [:last](http://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) selectors:

```
$("tr").each(function() {
    var firstId = $("span.select_me:first", this).attr("id");
    var secondId = $("span.select_me:last", this).attr("id");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

For first -

```
$("tr").each(function(){
    v = $(this).find("td:nth-child(1) span.select_me").attr("id");  
});
```

For second -

```
$("tr").each(function(){
    v = $(this).find("td:nth-child(2) span.select_me").attr("id");  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this -

```
 $("td").each(function(){
   first = $(this).find("span.select_me:eq(0)").attr("id");// for first 
   Second = $(this).find("span.select_me:eq(1)").attr("id");// for second 
    });
```

Comment: but I want the 1st or 2nd element, not both.

Answer (score 1):

nth-child may help: http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

```
$("tr td:nth-child(2) span.select_me").attr('id')
```